# Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False unable to edit other files

Tags: excel, vba

When I use `Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False` then I'm able to open other workbooks but unable to edit or even click on the new worksheet/do any manipulations.

Is there a way to edit or change any data in the opened workbook?

Thank you

This is the program i was speaking in the comments.

```
Private Sub cmbsendmail_Click()
    Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Save
    Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Protect

    Call Mail_Every_Worksheet_A1

    Range("C10:AH10").ClearContents
    Unload UserForm2 x Unload UserForm1

End Sub


Private Sub cmbsendmail_Exit(ByVal Cancel As x MSForms.ReturnBoolean)
    Range("C10:AH10").ClearContents

    Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Save
    Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Protect

    Unload UserForm2
End Sub
```

Comment: `Windows("MyWorkbook").Visible = False` should not affect other workbooks than MyWorkbook at all. Can you show a full working [mcve]? You need to be more detailed.

Comment: the program is too big to post here - suggestions please

Comment: That's why you should break it down to a [mcve]. I guess otherwise it will be hard to say anything.

Comment: Ok i will minimize as far as possible and get back to you - sorry for the delay, Thank you.

Comment: Private Sub cmbsendmail_Click() x 
Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Save x 
Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Protect x 
Call Mail_Every_Worksheet_A1 x 
Range("C10:AH10").ClearContents x 
Unload UserForm2 x 
Unload UserForm1 x 
End Sub x 
Private Sub cmbsendmail_Exit(ByVal Cancel As x MSForms.ReturnBoolean) x 
Range("C10:AH10").ClearContents x 
Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Save x 
Windows("ETY Tracker V1.2.xlsm").Protect x 
Unload UserForm2 x 
-
---
End Sub x sorry i am unable to post the program for which I have specified the lines with " x " for separation. Please consider.

Comment: Please always [edit] your original question to add code. Code in comments is almost unreadable.

Comment: There is no `.Protect` procedure for `Windows()` object. This code is incorrect and will throw an *"Object dosen't support this property or method"* error . Also your question is very unclear, you need to be much more precise in where exactly your issue is. I don't see what the code has to do with your question at all.